# C# - Send type as parameter and return a type based on it

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function that receive a dynamic object and a type as string.
I would like to cast the object to the type I have in my string.

```
 public void PostAutomaticRule(dynamic automaticRuleObject, string ruleType)
        {
            switch (ruleType)
            {
                case "Increase_budget":
                    ConvertToAutomaticRule(typeof(IncreaseBudgetRule), ref automaticRuleObject);
                    break;
            }
        }


 private void ConvertToAutomaticRule<T>(Type type, ref dynamic ruleObject)
        {
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(ruleObject);
            var c = serializer.Deserialize<type>(json);
        }
```

The class I am trying to convert to:

```
 public class IncreaseBudgetRule
    {
        public string automaticRuleName { get; set; }
        public string givePrioity { get; set; }
    }
```

I have many rules types so I want that function to receive a type and a object and will return an object of the type I sent in the function.
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: ConvertToAutomaticRule has an unused generic argument. I think that is what you are needing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the type in your ConvertToAutomaticRule-Method. You defined there a generic paramter which you can use as the type of the outcome. As the Deserialize-Method also accepts a generic Argument you can rewrite your methods like this:

```
public void PostAutomaticRule(dynamic automaticRuleObject, string ruleType)
{
    switch (ruleType)
    {
        case "Increase_budget":
            ConvertToAutomaticRule<IncreaseBudgetRule>(ref automaticRuleObject);
            break;
    }
}


private void ConvertToAutomaticRule<T>(ref dynamic ruleObject)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(ruleObject);
    var c = serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
}
```

**Edit (returning instead of using ref):**

You can also use the generic parameter to set is as return type.

```
public void PostAutomaticRule(dynamic automaticRuleObject, string ruleType)
{
    switch (ruleType)
    {
        case "Increase_budget":
            var increasedBudgetRule = ConvertToAutomaticRule<IncreaseBudgetRule>(automaticRuleObject);
            break;
    }
}


private T ConvertToAutomaticRule<T>(dynamic ruleObject)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(ruleObject);
    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
}
```

Comment: How can I return this object instead of using void and ref?

Comment: see my edits for an updated example without using of ref

Comment: Thank you @Mark, Why do you think someone down voted this question?

Comment: No idea sorry ;) You can try to ask that in the comments of your Question, that maybe the downvoter explains it

Answer (score 0):

try to change your generics to interfaces and that way you can do something like:

```
    var JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };

            var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IYourAutoSerializedObject>(automaticRuleObject.ToString(), JsonSerializerSettings);
```